# Cannot access my yarn application in aws port 3000

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to access my application in the browser, but despite several configuration attempts I still can't succeed.

My package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000 vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "lint": "eslint '*/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --color",
    "lint:fix": "eslint '*/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --fix",
    "lint:style": "stylelint 'src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'"
    "test": "jest --passWithNoTests --no-cache",
    "test:ci": "yarn test --coverage --noStackTrace --silent --ci --runInBand"
    "watch": "yarn test --watch",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
```

I have already enabled port 3000 in the security group in the console as shown in the image below:

[image]

I have also disabled the aws firewall

```
sudo ufw disable
```

When I run netstat -tlnp | grep 3000 the result is this

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3000 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN     
unix  2   [ ]           DGRAM    23000
```

it seems that my application is currently bound to the loopback address 127.0.0.1 on port 3000. This means that my application is only accessible from the local machine and cannot be accessed from outside the machine.

How to make it accessible from browser?

yarn start

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by editing the host in the package.json file as follows:

```
HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000 vite --host <your network IP address>
```